# How do I convert a string into code in Python?

Tags: python, string, pandas

## Converting a string to code

#### Noteworthy points:

- I'm new to coding and am testing various things to learn;
- i.e. yes, I'm sure there are better ways do achieve what I am trying to do;
- I would like to know any alternative / more efficient methods, however;
- I would also still like to know how to convert string to code to achieve my goal with this technique

So far I have looked around the forum and on google, and seen a few topics on this, none of which I can made work here, or which precisely answer the question from my perspective, including using `eval` and `exec`.

#### The Scenario

- I have a dataframe: `london` with 23 columns
- I want to create a dataframe showing all rows with 'NaN' values
- I have tried to use `.isnull()`, but it appears to only work on a single column at a time
- I am trying to achieve my desired result by using `|` to return any rows in any columns where `.isnull()` returns `True`

An **example of this working** with just two columns is:

```
london[(london['Events'].isnull() | london['Max Gust SpeedKm/h'].isnull())]
```

However, I need to achieve this result with all 23 columns, so I have attempted to complete this with some code.

#### Attempted Solution

- Creating a **string** containing all of the column headers
- i.e. `london[(london['`**Column Header**`'].isnull()` followed by `|` and then the next column
- Then using this **string** within the container shown in the working example above
- i.e. `london[(`**string**`)]`

I have managed to create the string I need using the following:

```
string = []
for i in (london.columns.values):
    string.append("london['" + i + "'].isnull()")
    string.append(" | ")
del string[-1]
final_string = "".join(string)
```

And finally when I try to implement the final step, I cannot work out how to convert this string into usable code.

For example:

```
now = eval(final_string)
london[now]
```

Resulting in:
`NotImplementedError: 'Call' nodes are not implemented`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should not be using `eval` for this purpose. You almost never should use `eval`. Anyway, I managed to get a similar example working. What version of `pandas` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = []
for i in (london.columns.values):
    string.append(london[i].isnull())
london[0<sum(string)]
```

Since you will have only 1 and 0 and you are looking for at least one 1 then you can just add 1,0's to your list then sum them. if the sum is more than one your if will turn 1 otherwise your if will turn 0 so you can do london index after that.

Comment: Hi ihsancemil - this works! But I don't understand why. Could you explain what the code is doing for me, perhaps by each line? In my head I'm reading it as each 'i' is a column header, then the append line is appending rows from the dataframe where there are null values, so the string should be a string of the rows?? I'm definitely misinterpreting somewhere. #NoobProblems

Comment: In first line you create a blank list, second you start looping, after that you giving you london[i] to boolean function that return 0-1 and the last line you sum that booleans because you want to chech if any 1 in your cases since you use | 'or' so you summing booleans for example you have 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 so your sum is 3 and 0<sum will be true which means 1 and you will use londen[1] another example you have 0, 0, 0 then sum will be 0 and you statement will be false which is 0 so you will call london[0].

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks for the explanation! One step closer to being employable thanks to you @ihsancemil

Comment: @JakeStokes I recommend you to look map, filter, reduce if you want to keep code in python they will improve your algorithm ability. You can use them almost every program you write.

Answer (score 4):

This is the easiest way to select the `rows` in your dataframe with `NaN` values:

```
df[pd.isnull(df).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for this Joe